# 7 or 8 of every 10 I (believe) have error connection with ##table

Tags: ssis, temp-tables

on ssis
I am working with ##tmptables
obviosly I am using RetainSameConnection to True
but if I execute my packege this fail when I have a select to this table or other (I have more than 1 ##table)

for example this is a (part of a) query's sql task

THIS DOES NOT FAIL ALWAYS.. but is failing aprox 8 of every 10 execution.
(on production when this fail, this get fail about 8 times continues(or more)) I have seen if I put a Break Point Before to execute this sql task and I copy and paste the code on sql manager and execute the query THIS WORK OK, and if I press play on visual studio(play to continue the process) this work OK)
other times I dont do nothing and this work OK.

```
declare @tablad nvarchar(max)
set @tablad =?

 declare @tipoprom as int

 set @tipoprom=?

 declare @mexico bit
 set @mexico=convert(bit,?)

declare @feccaja datetime
set @feccaja =?


declare @tabladinamica nvarchar(max)
set @tabladinamica=?


if(@mexico =1)
begin
return
end


declare @ordercode as table
(
id int
)
insert into @ordercode
exec('select id from ##'+@tablad+' where tabla=''[order]''')





select 
pro=opd.xxx,codbi=o.yyy,cedis=o.zzz,fecha=@feccaja,fechaactual=GETDATE (),aaa=o.bbb
 into #tmp
 from
```

...

```
declare @cadena varchar(max)
set @cadena ='

delete from ##prompro'+@tabladinamica+'
insert into ##prompro'+@tabladinamica+'
select * from #tmp

'
execute(@cadena)
```

[image]

if you need the error , it is.

[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query " my query " failed with the following error: "Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80040E37". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly. [image]

Comment: So you have code that fails intermittently. The error reported is the generic "something is wrong with your query". Is it always on the Buscar step or does it happen elsewhere? Could it be the parameters you are supplying violate the allowable types? I'm guessing that the script task is building those values? In your OnError event handler, I would dump the values of all my variables and attempt to correlate the values from a successful run to a non-successful one

Comment: not only on "buscar pedidos" this fail in other places where I user some ##table as you in the updated image.

Comment: and as I told, if I put a break point and copy and paste the query on sql manager and execute the query this work ok, and now if I quite "pause" this work (I believe) because I had first the query and worked..

Comment: But when you copy and paste the query, it does not run "as is". There are placeholders, `?` that have values substituted into them during run time. It is entirely possible that an unexpected value, a value that is out of allowable range, etc, is causing this to fail. We have screenshots of your failing package and fragments of queries. This is insufficient to anyone outside of your company to diagnose, much less resolve the issue

Comment: I had thought a "solution" I will not use ##temp tables I'll use a string with union all.. for example "select column1='a',column2=2 union all select column1='b', column2=51 " I haven't implemented, but I'll start to program it now.

Comment: I had finished of do that I told you and this works, but I dont know why now it does necesary drop table #table (tables with one #) I knew its dropped after executed, for that I used with double ##, now i need do drop table #